# SOAP message generator

Tags: java, soap

I need a tool that I give wsdl url and operation name after return me soap message construct.

There are some sites making this but I dont find any solution.

This sites  http://www.soapclient.com/soapclient, and I m using Java.

Is there any solution for this problem axis2?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org)

Comment: I need only soap message construct

Comment: Not sure what your comment means - SoapUI should do everything you require

Answer (score 0):

Indeed [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) can be used to create sample requests, when creating a new project in soapUI select the checkbox shown in the picture below, and in your navigator tree you should see "Test" which can be expanded to see sample requests.

[image: New Project dialog in soapUI]